# How to close cmd window openned bat file with another bat file or program

Tags: windows, batch-file

I created a node.js program, and I run it using the following `.bat` file:

```
cd C:\Users\user\Documents\programmingStuff\jsProgramsFolder
node .
@pause
```

I now want to close the cmd window created by this specific bat file with another bat file or program.

Searching for the answer only provided results for how to close the window in the same bat file.

Is this possible? If so, how can it be done?

Comment: It's not possible, unless you write an app that will do so specifically using the WinAPI. This would be relatively complex, because you'd have to figure out how to find the specific command window you want to close first, and there may be other command windows open. Why can't you just do it from this batch file?

Comment: @KenWhite It's a discord custom rich presence, so the custom status that is displayed will turn off when the command window is closed. If it is stopped from the batch file, the program will only run for a second and immediately turn off, making it essentially useless.

Comment: That would happen if you closed the command window from another batch file or program, too. Closing the window is closing the window, no matter how it happens.

Comment: @KenWhite I understand, what I want to do is essentially control when it would close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`taskkill` lets you filter by window title, and `title` lets you set the window title.

In the script that you have posted, add the line `title NodeLauncher` (you can call it something else as long as it's unique to this particular window.)

In another batch file, run `taskkill /IM cmd.exe /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq NodeLauncher"`